# How to post array to url in C# just like AngularJS $http.post(url, data)

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest

In AngularJs I could easily post data to an url by

```
$http.post(url, data)
```

data here is an array something like this :

```
["test1","test2","test3"]
```

My question is how can I do the same thing in C#? I want to use **HttpWebRequest**.

Comment: This is a good walkthrough of HttpWebRequest methods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ok the problem here is how can I convert arry  ["test1","test2","test3"] to post data?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ToList` on your array and `FormUrlEncodedContent` for your post request, see below

```
 using System.Net.Http;

 data.ToList(); //your data, assuming it is already a well-formed array or data model

 var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

 var response = await client.PostAsync("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx", content);

 var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: What about use HttpWebRequest instead of HttpClient? How can I do this with HttpWebRequest ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the answer myself.

payload here can be an array :

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

```
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = action;


        JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new UnderscoreMappingResolver(),
            Formatting = Formatting.None,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            Converters =
                {
                    new IsoDateTimeConverter
                    {
                        DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind
                    },
                    new StringEnumConverter
                    {
                        CamelCaseText = true
                    }
                }
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload, serializerSettings);
        request.ContentLength = json.Length;

        Console.Out.Write(request.RequestUri);

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                sw.Write(json);
            }
        }

        HttpWebResponse response;

        try
        {
            response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            response = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
        }
```